# Keyboard is behaving weird

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

When I try to type `cle` automatically the Edit-> Paste menu is opened in my terminal.

After that I am not able to enter anything in the terminal by keyboard.

Comment: Is any of the modifier keys (Ctrl/Shift/Alt) stuck?